# Laravel get redirected when opening register page when logged in

Tags: laravel, redirect, authentication

I want to create users when I'm logged in on a main account.
But everytime I open the "Sign up" page I will get redirect to http://domain/home.

I've already edited the controllers and removed /home there, but that still didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Please provide some information on how you have your routes/controller set up. I assume you have auth middleware in your sign up route. But you're leaving everything to the imagination really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `$this->middleware('guest');` from your **App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController**'s **__construct()** method in **app\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController.php**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create users while you're signed in, then you will need to create them programmatically through a controller. Have a UserController with a createUser method and within that put something along the lines of:

```
public function createUser() {
    $new_user = new User;
    $new_user->email = 'foo@bar.com';
    $new_user->name = 'john doe';
    $new_user->save();
}
```

As Avik said above, since the sign up page is handled by your RegisterController, it is not going to allow anyone who is authenticated to that page.